# Using transfrom translate property with absolute positioned elements

Tags: css, transform, absolute

I noticed something strange when trying to move an absolute positioned element with transform property even when using something like translateY(0) it moves the element abit which it should not move it at all
is this a normal behavior ?? and is there any workaround for it ??

I could not find anything on the internet related to this topic so I'm posting this here

**NOTE:** this issue happend on (Firefox) and it seems to work just fine on (Chrome)

---

I tried to reproduce the same problem using the code below

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box box-1"></div>
  <div class="box box-2"></div>
</div>
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;
  
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative; 
  width: 200px;
  height: 400px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.box {
  position: absolute; 
  width: 100%;
  
  border: 5px solid white;
  
/*
  if you toggle the next line you'll notice the bottom border line disappear and appear again
  */
  transform: translateY(0);
}

.box-1 {
  background-color: red;
  height: 25%;
  
}
.box-2 {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 75%;

  top: 25%;
}
```

you'll notice a line that has a comment above

as described removing the transform line will make the bottom border to reappear again

Comment: This could be caused by a few things; please post a [mre].

Comment: @Ry- here's a codepen I tried to reproduce the problem as best as I can https://codepen.io/salloom99/pen/OJoJEBj

Comment: I don’t see any difference with that Codepen. Which browser are you using?

Comment: I'm using firefox, are u using chrome ??

Comment: I tried in both Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: Please could you make your code into a runnable snippet and check that it really does show the problem when you run it. When I run the code exactly as you have given it I do not see the problem (Firefox on Windows 10). What OS are you on and are you absolutely sure there is no other code which might have an influence? (For example, which relies on stacking context)?

Comment: the issue magically disappeard when I restarted the system this morning I guess it was some weird bug on the browser